# How to write a stored procedure to insert values into two tables with a foreign key relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I created two tables, `Employeeinfo` and `Employeerequests`.

Table `Employeeinfo` can have one unique user with columns:

- id (primary key, auto increment)
- name
- dep
- address

and table `Employeerequests` can have multiple requests against one unique user ID with columns

- id (primary key, auto increment)
- CustomerID(foreign key to Employeeinfo(ID column))
- category
- requests.

Now I want to design a stored procedure in such a way so that I can insert values into both tables at the same time. Please help. I am very new to SQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Please help" isn't a question. Show use your attempts, explain why they didn't work. Or, show us the research you've performed to understand how to [Create a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) and tell us what you didn't understand about it. Then we can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

SQL Server only allows you to insert into one table in a single query.  You presumably want to provide both employee and request information.  So that limitation on `insert` is a real problem.

You *can* get around the limitation by creating a view combining the two table and then defining an `instead of insert` trigger on the view.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

That said, you seem to not have extensive SQL knowledge.  So, I would recommend simply using two separate statements, one for each table.  You can wrap them in a stored procedure, if you find that convenient.

Comment: actually i tried with two separate insert query in single procedure but geting error  foreign key conflict error in cloumn ID

Comment: You'll have to get the employee's newly created Id value and use that within the second insert statement. There are multiple ways to get this value, so depending on your scenario you might want to search for the best option. _@@IDENTITY_ could be something to start with.

Comment: @OnkelToob Exactly I want what you told. Do you have any example or any link..

Comment: As I said, _@@IDENTITY_ might be a good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql. There's other possibilities and of coure they all have advantages/disadvantages or even risks. But without knowing the details of your situation no one can tell. And please consider @larnu's comment. It's way easier to help if you let people know what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @OnkelToob . . . A better recommendation is `OUTPUT`.  It just works, regardless of the circumstances.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fun fact: `OUTPUT`is the option I've always gone with (it's been a while, though). No idea, why `@@Identity`was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure, you can use `Output` clause of `Insert` statement as:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (NewCustomerID INT);  

-- The OUTPUT clause have access to all the columns in the table, 
-- even those not part of Insert statement ex:EmployeeID.
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employeeinfo] ([Name], [dep], [address])  
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @MyTableVar  
    SELECT 'Test', 'TestDep', 'TestAddress'

-- then make insert in child table as   
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employeerequests] (CustomerID, category)  
    SELECT NewCustomerID, 'TestCat'
    FROM @MyTableVar
```

[Sample code here...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b17f3a54330b07106dd2656936e56c02)

Hope that helps!