# SQL Server 2005 Select Data From Table1 and Table2 but if Table2 column1 value is null Select Data From Table3

Tags: sql-server

My Query IS

```
SELECT TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo, TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo, InPatRegistration.PatTitle+PatientName, TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceNo, TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceDateTime, TblPharmacyBillingDetails.BillingAmount
FROM TblPharmacyBillingDetails
INNER JOIN TblMasterBillingData ON TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo = TblMasterBillingData.UPBNo
INNER JOIN InPatRegistration ON TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo = InPatRegistration.IPDNo
```

but if `TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo` value is `NULL` `select Data From TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo` and

```
INNER JOIN OutPatRegistration ON TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo = OutPatRegistration.IPDNo
```

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has long been out of support; you should *really* be looking at upgrade paths ASAP. Seems what you're after here is a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You can write a case statement also after joining the table.

Comment: Kindly provide Demo Query if Possible Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method #1: Using `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROm
(
    SELECT TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo, 
           TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo, 
           InPatRegistration.PatTitle+PatientName, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceNo, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceDateTime, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.BillingAmount
    FROM TblPharmacyBillingDetails
    INNER JOIN TblMasterBillingData ON TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo = TblMasterBillingData.UPBNo
    INNER JOIN InPatRegistration ON TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo = InPatRegistration.IPDNo 
    WHERE TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo, 
           TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo, 
           OutPatRegistration .PatTitle + PatientName, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceNo, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceDateTime, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.BillingAmount
    FROM TblPharmacyBillingDetails
    INNER JOIN TblMasterBillingData ON TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo = TblMasterBillingData.UPBNo
    INNER JOIN OutPatRegistration ON TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo = OutPatRegistration.OPDNo
    WHERE TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo IS NOT NULL
)Tmp
ORDER BY TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo
```

Method #2 Using  `ISNULL` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
    SELECT TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo, 
           ISNULL(TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo,TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo), 
           ISNULL(IP.PatTitle + IP.PatientName, OP.PatTitle + OP.PatientName), 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceNo, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.InvoiceDateTime, 
           TblPharmacyBillingDetails.BillingAmount
    FROM TblPharmacyBillingDetails
    INNER JOIN TblMasterBillingData ON TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo = TblMasterBillingData.UPBNo
    LEFT JOIN InPatRegistration IP ON TblMasterBillingData.IPDNo = IP.IPDNo 
    LEFT JOIN outPatRegistration OP ON TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo = OP.OPDNo 
    ORDER BY TblPharmacyBillingDetails.UPBNo
```

Comment: Query is working good but how to show data by order by no from Table1

Comment: @laxminarayan what is your criteria to order data ? the column(s) for sorting data ?

Comment: Order By No (No is column from Table1)

Comment: @Never Die Thanks for Methode 2 is useful for me but you posted query with minor mistake query is 
  LEFT JOIN outPatRegistration OP ON TblMasterBillingData.OPDNo = OP.OPDNo

Comment: @Never Die How to select data from using Method 2 where PatientName like'value%'

Comment: @laxminarayan You can add `WHERE` clause like `WHERE ISNULL(IP.PatientName, OP.PatientName) LIKE  'someting%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can write either `case statement` or `ISNULL()` function as shown below in the demo query.

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID, 
    Case when Customers1.CustomerName is null then Customers2.CustomerName else Customers1.CustomerName
        end as CustomerName, --way 1
    ISNULL(Customers1.CustomerName, Customers2.CustomerName) as Customer, --way 2
    Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers1 ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers1.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Customers2 ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers2.CustomerID
-- where your condition here
-- order by your column name
```

You can also check whether data is available or not in the table and join the table accordingly using `if exists` as shown below.

```
if exists(select 1 from tablename where columnname = <your values>)
```

Comment: @NeverDie I have just answered as the way to do and need modification.

Comment: Then do that, until you have clear picture dont post it as answer, instead your comment is enough.

Comment: @NeverDie Request you to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445250/10532500

Comment: @Suraj Kumar Query Not working - Query executed but data not selecting.